# CMake and librarian operation

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to get a COTS compiler/linker suite working with CMake and for the most part everything is working well.   The issue I am running into is with the librarian.

A typical call as defined in COMPILER-${lang}.cmake file would look like this:

SET(CMAKE_C_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY " -v -c  ")

but the librarian has no specific way of being told where the object files are so I would like to prepend the object files with the binary directory so as to give the librarian a specific place to find them.   However I can't come up with the right syntax to do so.

Any thoughts on how one would do this?

Answer (score 0):

After much work with the compiler/linker suite, it was determined that the main problem was that the compiler did not have the ability of being told where to put the object directly - in essence it did not support the typical -o parameter.

This resulted in the compiler naming the output file whatever it wanted and not paying attention to the  that was being passed to it by the make utility.

It also turns out that the main compiler executable was really just a wrapper for the preprocessor, code generator and assembler so I ended up just RE'ing it and building my own wrapper that did support the -o parameter.  It was definitively easier doing that trying to get CMake to work with this non-standard approach to generating outputs.  Once the compiler started supporting the -o parameter the librarian worked without any issues.